# How to remember last opened position in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Let's say I edit a file at line 1000. If I close the file and open it the next time, it will go to the first line. Any method to let it open at line 1000?

Comment: What version? For me `V8.4.8` it goes directly to the last hilighted line.

Comment: @Toto It seems this is behavior I want. I just updated it to v8.4.8 after seeing your comment, but it still doesn't go to the last highlighted line. Any settings I need to set?

Comment: I haven't done any specific setting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question - do you mean closing the file with Notepad++ still open or closing Notepad++ completely?

Answer (score 0):

I don't used notepad++ a long time, but if I remember correctly it should be something like:
Settings-->Preferences-->MISC Tab --> File Backup Section checkbox.
Let me now if it worked.

Comment: Looks like it has changed now. There is a specific backup setting session now. But seems none of the settings affect this. What editor do you use for subtitution btw?

Comment: At the moment I am using geany. Geany saves my current courser position and all opened files from last session (on linux). But it's not notepad++ of course.
Nevertheless, if you don't find any solution for notepad++ and want to try it out with geany, feel free to ask. I'm on linux and could provide my .config files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's impossible according to this post

https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/24022/how-to-remember-last-opened-position-in-notepad